# Use of context bound produces error in this code, why?

Tags: scala

Why does this code not compile and how do we do restrict `A` in `stuff` to a class with a functor instance?

```
object Main extends App {
  trait Functor[F[_]] {
    def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
  }
  implicit val listFunctor = new Functor[List] {
    def map[A,B](as: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = as map f
  }
  def stuff[A: Functor](a: List[A]) = {implicitly[Functor[List]].map(a)( b => "hi")}
  println("Hello, New Jersey!")
}
```

Comment: You are asking for a functor for **A**, not of **List**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Functor[F[_]` is a higher order type constructor meaning it takes a type *constructor* `F[_]` as type parameter and not a *proper* type A. If you write

```
def stuff[A: Functor](a: List[A])
          |
      proper type (*) instead of required type constructor (* -> *)
```

then it will expand to

```
def stuff(a: List[A])(implicit ev: Functor[A])
                                           |
                                         wrong kind of type parameter
```

Possibly you are trying to write something like

```
def stuff[F[_]: Functor, A](a: F[A]) = {
  implicitly[Functor[F]].map(a)(b => "hi")
}
```

or since your outer type is fixed to `List` you could avoid the context bound all together and just write

```
def stuff[A](a: List[A]) = {
  implicitly[Functor[List]].map(a)(b => "hi")
}
```